# Hide fetch errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've noticed that Chrome is logging all 4xx errors met by `fetch` while other browsers (at least Safari and Chrome) do not log them.

How can I prevent Chrome `fetch` from logging to console http request errors like 400 and 422?

Comment: do you have a `.catch` on your fetch's? - never mind, it still does it with a `.catch`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "Hide network messages" option to hide these in the Console. You will still be able to see the error in the Network tab.

### Before

[image: No Hide network messages]

### After

[image: Hide network messages]

If you want to filter particular error codes, you could use a regular expression to do this. The following **should** filter out any messages that contain 4, followed by 2 digits, followed by a space character, followed by ().

```
^((?!4\d{2}\s\(\)).)*$
```